# There was an error launching the application while executing .Desktop file in ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu-13.04

I have written a desktop script but when i try to execute the `.desktop` file as executable file then it's showing an error `There was an error launching the application`. I think, i have written the desktop file in correct format.

Here is the .desktop script Client Activity Monitor.Desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Client Activity Monitor
Terminal=true
Exec=/home/harsh/Server/server.sh
Icon=/home/harsh/Server/Server-icon.png
```

Here is server.sh script file

```
#!/bin/bash
cd Server
./refersh_server
```

refresh_server is executable file. 
Thank You

Comment: Try supplying the absolute path to `refersh_server` in `server.sh`

Comment: But, the same same script is working well on one system but it is not working on other system. In server.sh file 1st i have to change directory on terminal using cd server and then i have to execute refresh_server.

Comment: It works only when it is launched from a terminal session whose working directory is correct. Fix the script by using absolute paths instead of relative. (I'm guessing the `cd` is actually superfluous as well, unless the server -- sloppily -- expects to find its config or log files in its own working directory.)